# Magnific multiple popup strange behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, magnific-popup

I have a menu where there are several links to popup windows with forms. It looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/hr/applications/edit/15">Редактировать анкету</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Hr/PlaceUserInJobPopup?applicationId=15" class="magnific-form" type="inline">Трудоустроить</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Hr/RefuseUserApplicationPopup?applicationId=15" class="magnific-form">Отказать</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Hr/RenunciateUserApplicationPopup?applicationId=15" class="magnific-form">Отказался сам</a></li>
</ul>
```

My script for popups looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.magnific-form').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        closeOnContentClick: false,
        closeBtnInside: true,

        callbacks: {
            settings: null,
            parseAjax: function (mfpResponse) {
                console.log('Ajax content loaded:', mfpResponse);
            },
            ajaxContentAdded: function () {
                console.log(this.content);
            }
        }
    });
)};
```

And the forms with unobtrusive validation inside (they all look similar, nothin special):

```
<div class="popUp-content">
<form method="post" id="magnific-form" action="/Hr/RefuseUserApplicationPopup">        <div class="section-header">
            <div class="title">
                <h3 class="semibold black">
                    Отказать кандидату Высоцкая-Яблонович Анна Прохоровна
                    в должности Кассир
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-block">
            <img src="http://localhost:56804/content/images/thumbs/0000033_140.jpeg" title="Высоцкая-Яблонович Анна Прохоровна" alt="Высоцкая-Яблонович Анна Прохоровна" class="over-hidden round border-green-14">
            <div class="form-block-field">
                <label title="" for="Comment">Причина</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="Comment" id="Comment" data-val-required="Введите комментарий" data-val="true" cols="20"></textarea>
                <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Comment" class="field-validation-valid"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Отказать" class="btn marg-top-20" name="save">
</form>
</div>
```

And here is the forms onsubmit handler:

```
$(document).delegate('form', 'submit', function (event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var id = $form.attr('id');
    var _data = $form.serialize();
    var _type = $form.attr('method');
    var _url = $form.attr('action');

    if (id == 'magnific-form') {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            data: _data,
            type: _type,
            url: _url,
            success: function (response) {
                refreshPopUpContent(response);
            }
        });
    }

});

function refreshPopUpContent(response) {
    var magnificPopup = $.magnificPopup.instance;
    magnificPopup.items[0].type = "inline";
    magnificPopup.items[0].src = response;
    magnificPopup.updateItemHTML();

}
```

So the submit button click must return the form itself and validation errors via AJAX if ModelState.IsValid == false. Yes, but it works only with first popUp link in menu. The second and all other get the GET method from controller right after POST and there is no validation to see.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've changed the refreshPopUpContent method to:

```
function refreshPopUpContent(response) {
    var container = $('.popUp-content');
    container.html(response);
}
```

This will replace the content of popup with the view from controller, and the validation messages are visible.